# Looping through multiple pages of a JSON request (Guzzle, Laravel, PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, laravel-artisan

New dev here so I am sorry if this is a simple question or something like that but haven't been able to find exactly what I am looking for (it totally could be that I am not asking the question correctly either) Basically I have a paginated list coming back from an api and I am not sure what the logic would be to be able to cycle through those pages. Here is the code that I have so far that works perfectly for the first page lol.

```
    public function handle()
    {
        //This is the artisan command that runs on a timer and gets all the ticket and update fields that are needed and saves them to the database.
        $tickets = $this->pullTicketSummary();
        collect($tickets['data'])
            ->each(function ($currTicket) {

                $ticketRow = Tickets::query()->firstOrCreate(['ticket_id' => $currTicket['id']]);
                $ticketRow->status_id = $currTicket['status']['id'];
                $ticketRow->category_id = $currTicket['category']['id'];
                $ticketRow->user_id = $currTicket['assigned_to']['id'];
                $ticketRow->jira_issue_id = $currTicket['jira_issue_id'];
                $ticketRow->save();

                collect($currTicket['updates'])->each(function ($update) use ($currTicket){
                    $updateRow = Update::query()->firstOrCreate(['update_id' => $update['update_id']]);
                    $updateRow->ticket_id = $currTicket['id'];
                    $updateRow->assignee_change = $update['assignee_change'];
                });
            });
        Log::info('All tickets and updates were pulled successfully');
    }

    protected function pullTicketSummary()
    {       //Function makes the guzzle request and returns the response from the happyfox api
            $client = new Client();
            $request = $client->get('https://happyfox.com/api/1.1/json/tickets/?size=50&page=1',
                ['auth' => ['N/A']);
            $response = json_decode($request->getBody()->getContents(), true);
            return $response;

    }
```

With the fact that I am new if this is something that has been answered before that I missed please just shoot me over a link or if you are aware of any documentation that would help me get to the answer on my own that would be awesome! thanks!

Comment: What's up with the code? Its bit unclear to me where you need help with. Does it give errors?

Comment: `?size=50&page=1` ... I guess you need to change the page at some point.

Comment: @Arjan Nope! it works perfectly for the first page of the response but it is a paginated response and I am unsure of how to be able to have it loop through every page of that response on its own.

Comment: @Felippe Yup! its just that I dont know the best way to do that after doing some digging on my own.

Comment: Does the API shows the number of pages?

Comment: @Felippe yeah on postman it let me know that it is 1 of 203 pages however with more data that gets entered by the user that number will grow. So I was wondering if there was a way to be able to have it just keep going until it hits the ever increasing last page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your function to use the page number:

```
protected function pullTicketSummary($page)
{       //Function makes the guzzle request and returns the response from the happyfox api
        $client = new Client();
        $request = $client->get('https://happyfox.com/api/1.1/json/tickets/?size=50&page='.$page,
            ['auth' => ['N/A']);
        $response = json_decode($request->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        return $response;

}

//new function only to save the data from tickets variable. Necessary to reuse.
public function saveTicketsOrSomething($tickets)
{
    collect($tickets['data'])
        ->each(function ($currTicket) {

            $ticketRow = Tickets::query()->firstOrCreate(['ticket_id' => $currTicket['id']]);
            $ticketRow->status_id = $currTicket['status']['id'];
            $ticketRow->category_id = $currTicket['category']['id'];
            $ticketRow->user_id = $currTicket['assigned_to']['id'];
            $ticketRow->jira_issue_id = $currTicket['jira_issue_id'];
            $ticketRow->save();

            collect($currTicket['updates'])->each(function ($update) use ($currTicket){
                $updateRow = Update::query()->firstOrCreate(['update_id' => $update['update_id']]);
                $updateRow->ticket_id = $currTicket['id'];
                $updateRow->assignee_change = $update['assignee_change'];
            });
        });
}
```

Then iterate until you finish all the pages:

```
    $tickets = $this->pullTicketSummary(1); //first time
    $numPages = $tickets['numPages']; //update here to get the actual value of number of pages
    $this->saveTicketsOrSomething($tickets);

    for ($i = 2; $i < $numPages; $i++) { //start on 2, cause we already have fetched page 1
        $tickets = $this->pullTicketSummary($i); //other pages
        $this->saveTicketsOrSomething($tickets);
    }
    Log::info('All tickets and updates were pulled successfully');
```

Comment: Ahhhhh so I would end up making the logic for iterating over each page into its own function and not in the request itself. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do in the request itself. Anyway, if this solves for you, you can mark as accepted.

Comment: Ill be sure to report back!